# Iterative deepening depth-first search in arrays PHP

Tags: php

Would it be possible to implement IDDFS algorithm in PHP with arrays in levels?

Supposing the following tree:

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \   \  
D   E   F
```

Calling `getNodes(A)` results in Array(B, C), and likewise `getNodes(B)` in Array(D, E). I already wrote getNodes function, to use it together with the BFS algorithm which unfortunately is too slow.

Code formatted form comment:

```
function bfs($start,$target){
    $dist = 0; 

    if(empty($queue)){
        $queue = array(); 
    }; 

    if(empty($checked)){
        $checked = array();
    }; 

    array_push($queue, $start); 
    while(!empty($queue)):
        $dist = $dist + 1;
        $newqueue = array();

        foreach($queue as $node){
            if(!in_array($node,$checked)){
                array_push($checked,$node);
                $nodes=getNodes($node);
                if(checkNode($nodes,$target)){
                    return $dist;
                }else{
                    $newqueue=$nodes;
                }
            } 
            $queue = $newqueue; 
        } 
    endwhile;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: what about to show us your slow code?

Comment: DFS and BFS are equal in terms of speed. Can you please share your code for BFS? What exactly do you mean by slow?

Comment: are you familiar with recursivity?

Comment: smihael: you can edit your question to add additional information (like code) to it.

Comment: doesn't adding recursion to bfs result in more dfs-like behaviour?

Answer (score -1):

In a recursive point of view, a function to do this could look like this:

```
<?php

function getNode($needle, $target) {

    $res = null;
    foreach($target as $key=>$val) {

        if($key === $needle) {
            $res = $target[$key];
            break;
        }
        elseif(is_array($target[$key]))
            $res = getNode($needle, $target[$key]);
    }
    return $res;
}
```

tested with:

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => array(
        'b' => array(
            'water'
        ),
        'c' => array(
            'earth'
        )
    )
);

var_dump(getNode('a', $arr));
```

Comment: i'm not looking for a function that prints array tree, but for function that reads arrays, builds tree and finds a target in this tree.

Comment: getNode() does not print the array, it finds a node in it. var_dump() is printing it, for testing purposes only.

Comment: my bad, i got confused because getNode('earth', $arr) returns null

Comment: well, the function only looks for array indexes. I didn't know for sure your demands, so i just wrote an example of how could be the function. With some adaptation it could work for you.

Comment: Basically, by calling getNodes($root) array of nodes that are linked to $root is obtained, then using iteration all level 1 nodes are checked and so on. I thought it'd be faster with some depth limited recursion, which is exactly what IDDFS does.